# Raising exceptions in conditionals

Tags: ruby, exception

I'm trying to create a rock paper scissors program and so far this code works but the argument is not thrown, how can i fix this?

```
class RockPaperScissors

  # Exceptions this class can raise:
  class NoSuchStrategyError < StandardError ; end

  def self.winner(player1, player2)
    p1c = player1.last.downcase
    p2c = player2.last.downcase
    p1wins = false

    case p1c
      when "p"
        if (p2c == "p" or p2c == "r")
          p1wins = true
        end 
      when "s"
        if (p2c == "p" or p2c == "s")
          p1wins = true
        end
      when "r"
        if (p2c == "r" or p2c == "s")
          p1wins = true
        end
      else
        raise NoSuchStrategyError, "Strategy must be one of R,P,S" 
    end
  end
```

why does the error not throw?
EDIT*

this is used to test code using rspec, as you can see its a array with a Name followed by what they chose in a capse

```
before(:each) do
@rock = ['Armando','R'] ; @paper = ['Dave','P'] ; @scissors = ['Sam','S']
end
describe 'game' do
it 'rock breaks scissors' do
  RockPaperScissors.winner(@rock, @scissors).should == @rock
end
it 'scissors cut paper' do
  RockPaperScissors.winner(@paper, @scissors).should == @scissors
end
it 'paper covers rock' do
  RockPaperScissors.winner(@rock, @paper).should == @paper
end
it 'first player wins if both use same strategy' do
  RockPaperScissors.winner(@scissors, ['Dave','S']).should == @scissors
end
end
it "should raise NoSuchStrategyError if strategy isn't R, P, or S" do
lambda { RockPaperScissors.winner(@rock, ['Dave', 'w']) }.
  should raise_error(RockPaperScissors::NoSuchStrategyError,
  "Strategy must be one of R,P,S")
end
```

Comment: You need to include the code that shows how you're testing this. What is `player1` that has a `last` method? What is the value of `p1c`?

Comment: BTW, in no game of rock, paper, scissors that I've ever played does one player win when both players show the same strategy.

Comment: @Phrogz i know right its one of the requirments from my class i think its unfair as hell but oh well. tested using RSPEC code for test is included now

Comment: I don't think there's a problem raising an exception.  I simplified your code and inserted `p1c = 'catfish' and p2c = 'tuna'` right before `case`.  That raised the exception.  Then I changed p1c to `p1c = 's', and that too raised an exception.  When I also changed p2c to `p`, that returned true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Based on your newly-supplied test code, the problem is that you are only testing the strategy of the first player in your code. In the test code, however, the first player (`@rock`) has a valid strategy; it is the second player that has an invalid strategy. See my code for one way to test both.

---

It works for me when I add the missing `end` to your code and this:

```
Player = Struct.new(:last)
RockPaperScissors.winner(
  Player.new("cats"),
  Player.new("dogs")
)
#=> /Users/phrogz/Desktop/tmp.rb:24:in `winner': Strategy must be one of R,P,S (RockPaperScissors::NoSuchStrategyError)
```

Note that I would re-write your method like this:

```
class RockPaperScissors
  class NoSuchStrategyError < StandardError ; end
  LEGAL_MOVES = %w[r p s]
  def self.winner(player1, player2)
    p1c = player1.last.downcase
    p2c = player2.last.downcase
    unless LEGAL_MOVES.include?(p1c) && LEGAL_MOVES.include?(p2c)
      raise NoSuchStrategyError, "Strategy must be one of R,P,S"
    end
    if p1c!=p2c then
      case p1c
        when "r" then p2c=="s" ? player1 : player2
        when "p" then p2c=="r" ? player1 : player2
        when "s" then p2c=="p" ? player1 : player2
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This raises the error on an invalid move, returns `nil` if the two players tie, and otherwise returns one of the players. You can make it more terse by rewriting the inner portion like so, but arguably less clear:

```
if p1c!=p2c then
  case p1c
    when "r" then p2c=="s"
    when "p" then p2c=="r"
    when "s" then p2c=="p"
  end ? player1 : player2
end
```

Comment: I've edited my answer with the details on why your test is failing.